# How can i remove the denominator of all the Fractions

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, fractions, linear-equation

I used NumPy and Fractions module to find the answers to a given system of equations. But I want to convert all the answers to integers by dividing through by the highest denominator. How do I do that when I don't even know the values.

```
import numpy
from fractions import Fraction

a=[[3,4,1], 
   [2,3,0], 
   [4,3,-1]]
b=[[1], 
   [0], 
   [-2]]

values=numpy.linalg.solve(a, b)

for i in range(len(values)):
  num=values[i][0]  
  fractional_value=Fraction(num).limit_denominator()
  print(fractional_value)
```

Output:

-3/7
2/7
8/7

How do i remove the highest denominator assuming i dont know the output./

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimal number that a set of numbers divides is called the [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple). Python unfortunately doesn't provide this function out of the box, but we can calculate it from `gcd` (which Python *does* provide) and the product.

```
from math import gcd

def lcm(a, b):
  if a == 0 and b == 0:
    return 0
  return a * b // gcd(a, b)
```

Now we want to take a list of fractions and calculate the LCM of their denominators. I'll use a little tool called [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) (which really should be in `builtins`, but that's beside the point)

```
from functools import reduce

frac_list = [Fraction(-3, 7), Fraction(2, 7), Fraction(8, 7)] # Example list
denom_lcm = reduce(lcm, frac_list, 1)
```

Then we can multiply all of the fractions by this denominator.

```
whole_frac_list = [denom_lcm * x for x in frac_list]
```

and, of course, if we want values of the `int` type, we can get that too

```
whole_frac_list = [int(denom_lcm * x) for x in frac_list]
```